# how to use multidimensional array in inline javascript in thymeleaf 3

Tags: multidimensional-array, spring-boot, thymeleaf

As per documentation of Datatables.net https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html
i need to write some setting to data table implementation to my thmyeleaf template,

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable( {
     "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, [[${rowTotal}]]], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
   });
 });
</script>
```

But on rendering,it's giving me such error.

```
 org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, 'All'" (template: "customer/customerlist" - line 237, col 21)
```

And on reading this documentation on thymeleaf,it is being said 
`When inlining, if the expression between [[...]] is not a valid Standard Expression, it is output without modification, including the double-brackets.`
https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/22.

How to i solve this problem?

Comment: so what are you passing from the server side to the thymeleaf template? I only see plain javascript. you should put that in a js file and include it in the html file

Comment: edited question
-1 -> [[${rowTotal}]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I didn't know that was how it works in thymeleaf 2.  The easiest change would just be to format it differently.  Something like this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [
      [10, 25, 50, -1],
      [10, 25, 50, "All"]
    ]
  });
});
</script>
```

If that doesn't suit you, you could split the datatable definition into it's own javascript block and use `th:inline="none"` or move it to it's own external javascript file. (Why are you using `th:inline="javascript"` in this case anyways?).

Comment: Wow,It works like a charm.
Thanks @Metriods


I am using javascript
Since i need to pass total row and message for excel,pdf plugin supported by [http://datatables.net/].